# How can I easily detect finger joints on hand radiographs?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, dataset, object-detection

For a project in the medical image processing field I need to crop images of hand radiographs. More specifically I need to cut out the finger joints as these joints are markers for a specific disease. These cropped images of the joints is what i want to make a dataset of (for machine learning).

My question basically is, what is the best (or easiest way) to detect the finger joints in a hand radiograph?

I've searched the net, but it seems this has not been done before on radiographs.

I heard OpenCV could be used? If yes, how would I approach this best? I have not much experience with OpenCV (but am willing to learn it).

I tried Google's Mediapipe but it only works on real hand images (not on x-ray radiographs). I'd like to avoid training a ML-model from scratch as that means I need to label all the data I have and I have no time for that in this project.

Here is an example image that I would like to extract the joints of. What i need are the gray bounding boxes:
[hand radiograph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coq6K.jpg)

Comment: you don't have time to draw a couple dozen or hundreds of boxes on some images? that takes at most a few hours if your workflow is terrible. the training also won't take forever. these joints look fairly easy to spot, at least in these examples. you can then iterate on pictures where the model is not quite confident, i.e. annotate those cases manually and add to the training.